# Exporting custom geoprocessing tools from ModelBuilder to Experience Builder Web App

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, arcgis-online, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-experience-builder

I want to build an Experience Builder web app that incorporates custom geoprocessing tools I've built in ModelBuilder using ArcGIS Pro.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by the asker](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/430103/exporting-custom-geoprocessing-tools-from-modelbuilder-to-experience-builder-web/436295#comment701666_430103):

> This question has been resolved. I learned that it is not possible to
> integrate custom geoprocessing tools into Experience Builder yet (at
> least with a non-developer account), but that you can do it through
> the older AppBuilder using the geoprocessing widget. The process is to
> share the tool as a web tool from ArcGIS Pro using a properly configured
> portal (I believe it has to be an Enterprise account, though not
> positive). This generates a url that you can copy into the
> geoprocessing widget to embed the tool into the Web App.